# How can I pass a PHP variable to Javascript variable from two separate pages?

Tags: php, javascript, variables, external

I am trying to pass a PHP variable to Javascript variable for example:

```
<?php   $myvar=10;   ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jsvar = <?php echo $myvar; ?>;
    document.write(jsvar);
</script>
```

How could this be done separating the variable on another page? For instance Page1.html would have the document.write and the variable would be pulled from page2.php

Answer (score 5):

Only with Ajax. For example with jQuery:

```
$.get('page2.php', function(data) {
    alert( data );
});
```

...

**UPDATE**

Or alternatively (because smart people pointed out that there is always more than 1 way to go) you can include `page2.php` in your `page1.php` and the variable value will become available:

```
<?php
require_once('page2.php');
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jsvar = <?php echo $myvar; ?>;
    document.write(jsvar);
</script>
```

Comment: It's not "only with" AJAX, but it's potentially one approach. I think the better approach might be looking to update the design ;-)

Comment: @pst sure thing :) but redesigning the project is kinda out of the scope of this question

Comment: Hey thanks, I will try using the ajax route, but to my knowledge the page I am trying to push the info to can only use html and javascript (sorry I didnt explain that earlier otherwise the php include would have worked no problems). I am currently using get innerhtml by id to pass the information that I want to echo to change the Div on "page1.html" but from what I see its not a SEO friendly approach. Maybe there is a way to make the approach more SEO-able